# Using Google Earth imagery data for portable solution?

Tags: data, google-earth

I wish to clarify with users who are using Google Earth portable solution. As per portable solution link http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/portable.html, we can create part of globe and create offline map to use it.

However FAQ section in : http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/earth_enterprise_faq.html mentioned as below:
Does the Google Earth Portable solution allow you to use Google's imagery?
No, the Google Earth Enterprise portable solution is intended to be used in situations where your employees need to access your internal imagery and mapping data. Google does not provide customers with Google licensed data for portable use. Google has many partners that provide custom Google Earth Enterprise portable solutions with high resolution imagery.

Then i am not sure how to use portable solution in offline without Google's imagery data. Any experiences or details on this solution are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to download Google imagery; that would be a violation of the terms of service. You can, however, under/overlay the imagery via a Google Earth Pro account with your own data in Google Earth Enterprise.

Google Earth Portable allows you to "cut out" an area of your globe from Google Earth Enterprise. Portable literally takes all the data & imagery from all the layers that is within the boundaries of your specified polygon and creates a new Portable globe that can be hosted on a flash drive or laptop. No internet connection required.

We have built them for post-hurricane response in the South. Portable was built for use in disaster areas and is being used in Japan right now.

navagis.com

Comment: @user2716: Could you clarify your statement "Portable literally takes all the data & imagery from all the layers that is within the boundaries of your specified polygon and creates a new Portable globe"  means whether it includes Google's layers for that boundaries as well?

Answer (score 1):

The SELECTED data is stored on the local machine (not quite a cache more a database).

More interesting is

> "Previously if a client wanted to
>   access a Google Earth Enterprise
>   database (3D Globe) disconnected from
>   their network they would need to use
>   VM Ware running a Earth Server with
>   complete Google Earth Databases
>   published to it.  Now with the new
>   Globe Creator a virtual machine is no
>   longer required and clients can now
>   clip out portions of globes."

http://blog.firstbasesolutions.com/news/google-earth-enterprise-portable-globe-creator/

(it seems to store it in cross between fusion tables and app engine offline)

Comment: As per FAQ, it is not possible/allowed to download Google licensed data for portable use.. is it?

Comment: Keyword is "Enterprise" if you have the enterprise products then you have already paid the license ($10k)

Comment: As per my understanding, Google Earth Portable solution not available for normal user and only for enterprise users.