# Google Earth Enterprise Portable Server replacement?

Tags: google-earth

Is anyone still using Google Earth Enterprise Portable Server? Is there a better alternative now? "The Google Earth Enterprise Portable Server solution enables organizations to access portions of their custom globes in the field when no network access may be available or possible." This is exactly what I am looking for.

All of the references to it that I found were at least 3 years old. 
https://support.google.com/earthenterprise/answer/4485225?hl=en#google_earth_api

Reference from 2011:
[Using Google Earth imagery data for portable solution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/google-earth-portable-solution-and-imagery-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available via open source (Google open sourced it in 2017) https://github.com/google/earthenterprise/wiki/Portable-Server

Supported versions are available from http://www.t-sciences.com/google-earth-enterprise

Comment: Do you know if Google will switch the Google Earth server off? I.e. will there be a point when you open the GE client on your desktop and there won't be any data available to load the actual globe? If you know anything, could you add this info to your answer?

Comment: Google has been investing in mobile (via android) and web (via chrome) interfaces to their existing Google Earth content stores.  Data ranging from their 3D mesh of cities, Terrain, Imagery, Streetview, etc. are being exposed through those apps.  The Google Earth client can consume the same specification of data that Google is using.  The web, mobile, and desktop all use that same specification.  So, it's likely that content will be there as part of Google's future plans.  The client can consume it just like the other interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "Google Earth Enterprise Portable" Server that was part of GEE 4.4.1 is also in GEE 5.0:

"Google Earth Enterprise Portable (GEE Portable) lets you view portable globes and maps on your laptop or desktop without requiring network access. This is useful for emergency responses to disasters like earthquakes or floods, or for maps that contain private information that you don’t want to share on the internet."
https://support.google.com/earthenterprise/answer/3230746