# Google Earth data backup

Tags: data, google-earth, image

Is it possible to have data backup? If so how long?

Except Google Earth is there any other authentic system that can provide cultivations image data of a field for last few years?

Comment: I believe Google uses, at least in part, publicly available satellite and airplane imagery. They do some imaging on their own, but the bulk of their material is obtained from the public domain.

Comment: Concerning downloading Google's data [Using Google Earth imagery data for portable solution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/using-google-earth-imagery-data-for-portable-solution?rq=1)

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.